# How to Type Cast Sobject List to custom object List in Apex to access custom object fields

Tags: apex, list, sobject, typecast

Let's consider the below scenario:

I have a scenario to type cast sObjectList into the List<customObject__c> so that I can access customObject fields and store it into the following:

```
String customValue1 = '';
String customValue2 = '';
String customValue3 = '';
String customValue4 = '';
```

Based on the recordId I'm fetching the `targetobjectApi` name and getting the fields to query on this object from the custom metadata created.

After constructing the SOQL - `String soqlQuery = 'SELECT ' + fields + ' FROM ' + targetObjectApiName; // It returns the sobject List`

Now in the switch case I have to write a logic to convert this sobject list returned into `customObject__c` list so that I can access fields on the `customObject__c`.

Please find the code below:

```
String recordId = 'a2r540000014DwFAAU'; 

//Create String to store the query 
String query = ''; 
String fields = ''; 

//Create String to store custom Object values  
String customValue1 = '';
String customValue2 = '';
String customValue3 = '';
String customValue4 = ''; 


//Create List to Store customObject__c 
List<customObject__c> customObjectList = new List<customObject__c>(); 


Id newId = Id.valueOf(recordId);
String targetObjectApiName =  newId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();

System.debug('targetObjectApiName-------->' + targetObjectApiName);

//Get Fields From Custom Metadata
List<customMetadata__mdt> customMetadataRecords = [SELECT Field__c, Object__c FROM customMetadata__mdt WHERE Object__c = :targetObjectApiName]; 
System.debug('customMetadataRecords---------->' + customMetadataRecords); 

if(customMetadataRecords!=null && !customMetadataRecords.isEmpty()){
    for(customMetadata__mdt mdtObj: customMetadataRecords){ 
        fields = mdtObj.Field__c; 
        System.debug('fields---------->' + fields);
    }
}

//Construct SOQL Query 
String soqlQuery = 'SELECT ' + fields + ' FROM ' + targetObjectApiName; 
System.debug('soqlQuery----------->' + soqlQuery);

List<sObject> sObjectList = Database.query(soqlQuery); 
System.debug('sObjectList--------> ' + sObjectList);

//Store Values 
if(sObjectList!=null && !sObjectList.isEmpty()){
    switch on targetObjectApiName {
            when 'customObject__c' {    
               //Need help here in typecasting
               customObjectList = (List<customObject__c>) sObjectList; 
               //Need help here in storing customField__c values 
               customValue1 = customObjectList[0].customField1__c;
               customValue2 = customObjectList[0].customField2__c;
               customValue3 = customObjectList[0].customField3__c;      
               customValue4 = customObjectList[0].customField4__c;
              
            }
            when else {      
                return 'Other Option';
            }
        }//End Switch 
}

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just statically declare the type in this switch block. Keeping it dynamic once you have gotten this far adds little (if any) value.

```
switch on targetObjectApiName {
    when 'customObject__c' {
        List<CustomObject__c> concreteRecords = sObjectList;
        CustomObject__c record = concreteRecords[0];
        customValue1 = record.CustomField1__c;
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to cast the records at all. The `SObject` base class provides the `get` method that allows retrieval of a field value (as `Object`, which can be converted to a string using `String.valueOf`, for example). As long as you can get the field API names from your custom metadata, you can pass them in to this `get` method to find the field values.

You can, of course, use the object type name to retrieve the relevant custom metadata record(s) too.

See the SObject [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) for more detail.

Comment: Dynamic `get` calls tend to be slower than static field paths, so there could be performance implications.

Comment: If they are using custom metadata records with entity and field definitions then that will have a far bigger performance impact (unless this has been massively improved in the last 3 or 4 platform releases). It was terrible when I last tested it.

Comment: @adrianlarson I would also say it is better not to optimize early. Better to actually measure and improve if necessary.

Comment: Right that's kind of what I'm saying. Dynamic `get` calls are poor performance.

Comment: But if the solution requires use of admin-set custom metadata to map the detail, hard-coding doesn't fit the requirement.

Comment: Not always true.